# Page break in static points

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, page-break

I have a page with two dynamic tables.

When I want to print my page, each of my tables will be separated, one side in one page and other side in other pages. (both tables are dynamic)

I want to make static page break in any 672px

I did many way, but still I didn't get response.
Is there anyway for me?

My HTML:

```
<table id="selectedTable" style="width: 100%; font-size: 12pt; margin-top: 2px; text-align: right; border-top: 4px solid #000000; border-right: 4px solid #000000;border-left: 4px solid #000000;">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="{{(TotalDetailsOfUsagesCurrent.length * 2) + 2}}TotalDetailsOfUsagesCurrent">Blah blah</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="53px">
         <div style="text-align: center;">Usage</div>
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat='TDUC in TotalDetailsOfUsagesCurrent track by $index' colspan="2">
         {{TDUC.UsageType}}
      </td>
      <td width="55px" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #000000; border-top: 2px solid #000000;  font-size: 12pt;text-align: center; ">
         <div>Total</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="selectedRow" ng-click="heightChecker(this)" ng-repeat='DFC in DetailsOfFloorsCurrent'>
      <td width=" 53px">
         <div dir="ltr"> {{getFloorName(DFC.FloorNo)}} </div>
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat-start="usage in DFC.Usages track by $index">{{usage.UnitNo}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat-end>{{usage.UnitArea}}</td>
      <td width="55px">
         {{DFC.TotalAreaCurrent.toFixed(2)}}
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div>Total</div>
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat-start="TDFC in TotalDetailsOfUsagesCurrent">{{TDFC.UnitNo}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat-end>{{TDFC.UnitArea.toFixed(2)}}</td>
      <td>{{TotalAreaCurrent.toFixed(2)}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$scope.heightChecker = function (row) {
    selectedRow[row.$index].offsetTop; //it gives me my row distance from top of table. for getting the pixles. but its usless

}
```

Comment: Post your relevant codes or create [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Also your issue is not clear. What you want explain precisely

Comment: I want to make page break inside my html rows after any 672 Pixles started by top of my page (not top of my table).

Comment: Just an idea: How about creating a print.css (media="print") and fixing the height of the body at 672px?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp). You can mark your rows with some class, and edit the css to add page break after each table row with this class.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful. but its not my answer yet.

Comment: Set fix size of the for each row, than you can set the css using `:nth-child()` selector.

Comment: But my rows has different sizes. maybe 10px maybe 100px

Comment: I found, i have to use display: block; in my css.
But it makes y table messy....
Any other solution?